# Gmail Actions in Inbox - debugging after domain registration

Tags: google-schemas

I cannot figure out how to set up Gmail Inbox Actions. I sent an email to gmail-schema-whitelisting-samples@google.com, then filled in the registration form. However, schemas are not showing up.

Should they work immediately after registration? My SPF and DKIM records seem to be fine. I send all emails from registered domain in quoted-printable encoding, could it be the reason for schemas not showing up?

`Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of pm_bounces@pm.mtasv.net designates 50.31.156.118 as permitted sender) client-ip=50.31.156.118;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of pm_bounces@pm.mtasv.net designates 50.31.156.118 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=pm_bounces@pm.mtasv.net;
       dkim=pass header.i=inbound@livechatinc.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request will be manually reviewed and a Google representative will contact you for further details or to update you on the status of the approval. Quoted-printable encoding is supported.